# SilverLight / WPF Button with DropDown

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Is it possible to create a button with a drop down, or a combobox that has the dropdown arrow along the bottom as opposed to the right hand side? I am trying to emulate the "Paste" button in the Word 2010 ribbon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used it with success, but only on the right-side.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/delay/splitbuttoning-hairs-two-fixes-for-my-silverlight-splitbuttonmenubutton-implementation-and-true-wpf-support)

However it is customizable to the point where you may manipulate the _contextMenu.HorziontalOffset and _contextMenu.VerticalOffset to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small sample that you get the right idea how to accomplish that. But it's not the word like button:

http://www.tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=140

Comment: Hi @MUG4N, I found that, but it doesnt seem to work. Popup has no "PlacementTarget" property, not sure if thats silverlight 4.